# Is there a way to get Windows to handle Shift + numpad keys differently?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, windows-7, keyboard, mouse, windows

I have a Razer Naga gaming mouse. The mouse has a number grid on the side that acts like a numpad. I know this can be remapped, but I would like it to use the Numpad keys. In Windows, when you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> it actually sends the <kbd>up arrow key</kbd> to the application/game. Is it possible to get Windows to actually sent a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> key to the application/game instead? I would, of course, like to do this for the other NumPad keys as well.

I want to use this for binding character abilities in World of Warcraft on Windows 7.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just ended up remapping those side buttons to letters and punctuation that is not being used by the game. If anyone has any ways to actually achieve what I was originally going after, that would be cool, but I don't know if there is a good way to do it.

Comment: Our Help Center says that questions about "Game-specific hardware and utilities" are on-topic, and this question is exactly about configuring and MMO mouse correctly. This should be reopened.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Remapping keys in Windows is not exclusive to games.

Comment: @Wrigglenite The question is about using a game-specific mouse: while you can certainly use it for other things, chances are, you will see a gaming expert here who has done it. Asking this question on a non-games-related website is less likely to attract someone who has personally experienced this issue.

Comment: @Joachim OP tagged their question with [tag:world-of-warcraft] and [tag:windows-7], but tags should describe the content of the question and be based on it, not introduce something entirely new to the context. Without the tag or any trace of WoW in the question body, only a game-agnostic answer is accepted, but OP clearly needed this for WoW, so a WoW-specific answer should be OK.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Oh yes, my apologies. I didn't notice the original tags already included WoW.

Answer (score 5):

A [quick search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=shift+numpad) reveals several such questions about this setup and the functionality you request for WoW and other MMOs. **The only consistent solution that seems prevalent and that works for most it seems is the use of [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).** [Here's a WoW related thread of suggested setup](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2878699926).

Comment: After trying this option, I couldn't get it to work. The buttons would keybind correctly, but would also trigger a Numlock On/Off keypress as well. Also even though the keybind did work correctly, it would never actually trigger the button in game. Not sure why.